# Webscraping data from basketball-reference

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to webscrape some data from a website, but I'm having issues filtering the data into a set of results.

I would like to have a DF cointaining all advanced stats from the 2018-19 season.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

headers = {'User-Agent': 
           'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.106 Safari/537.36'}

page = "https://www.basketball-reference.com/players/c/curryst01.html"
pageTree = requests.get(page, headers=headers)
pageSoup = BeautifulSoup(pageTree.content, 'html.parser')

dados_agrupados = pageSoup.find_all("div", {"id": "all_advanced"}, recursive=True)

print(dados_agrupados)
```

As you can see, the object dados_agrupados contains the complete historical data and some other information.

How could I futher filter this data to get the stats from specifically the 2018-19 season?

Comment: what do you mean you want `"all advanced stats from the 2018-19 season"`? That's just 1 row in that 1 table. Do you want the advanced states foe every game of that season?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the advanced stats table, you need to pull it out of the html comments (which is where it is located). And I'm not sure what you mean by wanting all `"all advanced stats from the 2018-19 season."`

There is only one table here with `id="all_advanced"` and 1 row for that season. If you mean you want to go to that link, and pull that table, then that's another thing. But you aren't very clear.

So here's to pull that table, then filter on that season/row:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, Comment
import pandas as pd

headers = {'User-Agent': 
           'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.106 Safari/537.36'}

page = "https://www.basketball-reference.com/players/c/curryst01.html"
pageTree = requests.get(page, headers=headers)
pageSoup = BeautifulSoup(pageTree.content, 'html.parser')
comments = pageSoup.find_all(string=lambda text: isinstance(text, Comment))

tables = []
for each in comments:
    if 'table' in each:
        try:
            tables.append(pd.read_html(each, attrs = {'id': 'advanced'})[0])
        except:
            continue

df = tables[0]
df_filter = df[df['Season'] == '2018-19']
```

**Output:**

```
print (df.to_string())
     Season   Age   Tm   Lg  Pos    G     MP   PER    TS%   3PAr    FTr  ORB%  DRB%  TRB%  AST%  STL%  BLK%  TOV%  USG%  Unnamed: 19   OWS   DWS     WS  WS/48  Unnamed: 24  OBPM  DBPM   BPM  VORP
0   2009-10  21.0  GSW  NBA   PG   80   2896  16.3  0.568  0.332  0.175   1.8  12.0   6.8  24.6   2.5   0.5  16.5  21.8          NaN   3.0   1.6    4.7  0.077          NaN   1.1  -0.5   0.7   2.0
1   2010-11  22.0  GSW  NBA   PG   74   2489  19.4  0.595  0.325  0.216   2.3  10.9   6.5  28.1   2.2   0.6  16.4  24.4          NaN   5.4   1.3    6.6  0.128          NaN   3.0  -0.7   2.3   2.7
2   2011-12  23.0  GSW  NBA   PG   26    732  21.2  0.605  0.409  0.159   2.3  11.3   6.8  32.3   2.8   0.8  17.0  24.0          NaN   1.8   0.4    2.2  0.144          NaN   4.1   0.3   4.3   1.2
3   2012-13  24.0  GSW  NBA   PG   78   2983  21.3  0.589  0.432  0.210   2.3   9.1   5.8  31.1   2.1   0.3  13.7  26.4          NaN   8.4   2.8   11.2  0.180          NaN   5.3   0.1   5.4   5.6
4   2013-14  25.0  GSW  NBA   PG   78   2846  24.1  0.610  0.445  0.252   1.8  10.9   6.4  39.9   2.2   0.4  16.1  28.3          NaN   9.3   4.0   13.4  0.225          NaN   6.3   1.1   7.4   6.7
5   2014-15  26.0  GSW  NBA   PG   80   2613  28.0  0.638  0.482  0.251   2.4  11.4   7.0  38.6   3.0   0.5  14.3  28.9          NaN  11.5   4.1   15.7  0.288          NaN   8.2   1.7   9.9   7.9
6   2015-16  27.0  GSW  NBA   PG   79   2700  31.5  0.669  0.554  0.250   2.9  13.6   8.6  33.7   3.0   0.4  12.9  32.6          NaN  13.8   4.1   17.9  0.318          NaN  10.3   1.6  11.9   9.5
7   2016-17  28.0  GSW  NBA   PG   79   2638  24.6  0.624  0.547  0.251   2.7  11.4   7.3  31.2   2.6   0.5  13.0  30.1          NaN   8.7   3.9   12.6  0.229          NaN   6.7   0.3   6.9   5.9
8   2017-18  29.0  GSW  NBA   PG   51   1631  28.2  0.675  0.580  0.350   2.7  14.4   9.0  30.3   2.4   0.4  13.3  31.0          NaN   7.2   1.9    9.1  0.267          NaN   7.8   0.0   7.7   4.0
9   2018-19  30.0  GSW  NBA   PG   69   2331  24.4  0.641  0.604  0.214   2.2  14.2   8.4  24.2   1.9   0.9  11.6  30.4          NaN   7.2   2.5    9.7  0.199          NaN   7.1  -0.5   6.6   5.1
10  2019-20  31.0  GSW  NBA   PG    5    139  21.7  0.557  0.598  0.317   3.0  17.8  10.1  42.3   1.7   1.3  14.6  33.6          NaN   0.2   0.1    0.3  0.104          NaN   4.5  -0.6   3.9   0.2
11   Career   NaN  NaN  NBA  NaN  699  23998  23.8  0.623  0.481  0.237   2.3  11.8   7.2  31.5   2.5   0.5  14.2  27.9          NaN  76.5  26.7  103.2  0.207          NaN   6.0   0.4   6.4  50.7
```

and the filter:

```
print (df_filter.to_string())
    Season   Age   Tm   Lg Pos   G    MP   PER    TS%   3PAr    FTr  ORB%  DRB%  TRB%  AST%  STL%  BLK%  TOV%  USG%  Unnamed: 19  OWS  DWS   WS  WS/48  Unnamed: 24  OBPM  DBPM  BPM  VORP
9  2018-19  30.0  GSW  NBA  PG  69  2331  24.4  0.641  0.604  0.214   2.2  14.2   8.4  24.2   1.9   0.9  11.6  30.4          NaN  7.2  2.5  9.7  0.199          NaN   7.1  -0.5  6.6   5.1
```

Comment: So what did you mean with wanting 2018-2019? Was it just that 1 row, or to go into the season and get each game for that 2018-19 season?